# Can't sync Gradle in Android Studio in Iran

Tags: android-studio, gradle, synchronization

I use Android Studio version 1.5.1,
and I'm trying to compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' in build.gradle, but I can't sync Gradle.
I think this error is because of my Internet connection or access being blocked from my country (Iran).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's because Google has been blocked in Iran since 2012.
You can use a proxy app like Shadowsocks to change your country.

After activating your proxy app, in Android Studio go to
file->setting->Appearance & Behavior->System Setting->HTTP Proxy
active 'Manual proxy configuration'

and set:

- host name:127.0.0.1 (for example)
- port name:1080 (for example)

and reset Android Studio. When Android Studio resets, activate the HTTPS proxy and sync your Gradle and it will work. ;)

Comment: Google has blocked Iran. It's not blocked.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly Google as an american company has to obey US foreign policies. Google has too many services, among them those which relate to developers are blocked. There are many ways to work around these bans using proxies and VPNs but i personally wish for changes to happen between Iran and US.

Answer (score 0):

> you have to install any connect and set cisco username and password
>   and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Put this info in your Android Studio **proxy settings**:

```
address: fodev.org
port:8118
```

Put these lines on **gradle.properties** file in your project:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
```

[image]

For more information see this **repository**: https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod