# Error" Could not find aapt2-windows.jar "

Tags: android

I face this error when i am trying to run app in AVD in Android Studio 3.3. And I have to say I have tried adding google() in gradle . actually it was there before i face this problem .I downloaded the jar file from the link that error gives me , but I donot know where to put it.So please if you have a solution different with google(), please share it. Thanks in Advance

Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-5013011).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


//Thanks

Comment: https://ufile.io/er80kneb

Comment: https://ufile.io/85w7b1rl

Comment: build.gradle looks ok. Is the link from your question woking (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar)?

Comment: Also check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686832/cant-sync-gradle-in-android-studio-in-iran

Comment: @MohammadNorouzi did you find any answer? I have the same problem

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65195608/6401241

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral()` in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```